# Issue with stubing a instance method and returning series of values in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub, stubbing

I have stub a instance method for class User and returning sequence of string of values.

`User.any_instance.stub(:name).and_return('abc', 'pqr', 'xyz')`

My code is

```
users = User.where.not.(phone: nil)
users.each do |user|
    name = user.name
end
```

For all the calls of name method it returns 'abc'. When I tried to debug using 'byebug' in 'do' loop and called method 'name' it was returning value in sequence. But it is not working in normal condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
User.any_instance.stub(:name).and_return('abc', 'pqr', 'xyz')
```

This will return different value only when the `name` method is called multiple times on the same instance `user`, in your case `name` is called on a different instance of the `user`, which is why it returns `abc` always. [Specify different return values for multiple calls](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value#specify-different-return-values-for-multiple-calls)